# How to add argument to executed R function?

Tags: r

If I have executed a function, but didn't specify one argument, but then when to "add" the argument later on, how would I do this?

Importantly, I want to keep the parameters set when it first gets executed, and just add a parameter to the second execution.

```
test.fun <- function(a, b = NULL) {

  if (b) {
    c <- a * 2 * b
  }

  else {
    c <- a * 2
  }

  return(c)
}




fun <- test.fun(2)

new_fun <- fun(# plus argument b = 4)
```

Comment: You have to recall the function. A call can't be modified once it has been evaluated (because it doesn't exist anymore).

Answer (score 1):

You want

```
new_fun <- function(a) {
  test.fun(a, 4)
}
```

Comment: Hah, so simple! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to do it with `missing` and returning a list with value and parameters:

```
test.fun <- function(a, b = NULL) {

  if (!missing(b)) {
    c <- a * 2 * b
  }

  else {
    c <- a * 2
  }

  return(list(value = c, arguments = list(a = a, b = b)))
}




fun <- test.fun(2)
new_fun <- test.fun(a = fun$arguments$a, b = 4)
```